# Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript not showing messages for 2nd time

Tags: c#, alert

I'm using `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` for displaying alert messages. it works fine for the first message, however second message wont display. Though it passes through the code while debugging.

Below is the code. Here only *FiveDot File uploaded successfully* message is displayed.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('FiveDot File uploaded successfully');", true);
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('TwoDot File uploaded successfully');", true);
```

I've to show multiple alert messages in the webpage based on certain conditions.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use different type or key to register second script as:

> A client script is uniquely identified by its key and its type.
>   Scripts with the same key and type are considered duplicates. Only one
>   script with a given type and key pair can be registered with the page.
>   Attempting to register a script that is already registered does not
>   create a duplicate of the script.

(taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

or just concatenate both script string.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('FiveDot File uploaded successfully'); alert('TwoDot File uploaded successfully');", true);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use different keys

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('FiveDot File uploaded successfully');", true);
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox1", "alert('TwoDot File uploaded successfully');", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

solution with more than one popup modal type

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"), "openModal('" + id + "','" + Title + "','" + Message + "');", true);
```

Below script shall be kept in master page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openModal(id, title, message) {
        $('#' + id + ' .modal-header h4').html(title);
        $('#' + id + ' .modal-body').html(message);
        $('#' + id).modal('show');
    }
</script>
```

Here parameter id holds the respective bootstrap modal(default, info, danger, warning, success)

place the below in master page form tag, then repeat the same by replacing the class name "modal-primary" with "modal-info","modal-warning", "modal-dialog","modal-success","modal-danger".

```
<div class="example-modal">
  <div class="modal modal-primary" id="primaryModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Primary</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
<!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div>
<!-- /.modal -->
</div>
<!-- /.example-modal -->
```

In your master page add reference to bootstrap.min.js  and  bootstrap.min.css

This will enable the bootstrap model popup.

reference: [source](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)