# VB call javascript resource code behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to pass a string and call a javascript function from the code behind in vb.net, once I click a button. The javascript is in a separate file.

Below is the code for the button:

/MyProject/myfile.aspx

```
<HTML>
...
...
<asp:textbox id="txtSearch" runat="server" Width="120px" CssClass="midField"></asp:textbox>
<input class="midBtn" id="btnSearch" type="button" value="Search" name="btnSearch" runat="server">
...
...
<script src='<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/script/functions/myFunc.js")%>' ></script>
</HTML>
```

/MyProject/myfile.aspx.vb

```
Private Sub btnSearch_ServerClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.ServerClick
   Dim searchString As String
   searchString = txtSearch.Text
   Dim rsname As String = Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/script/functions/myFunc.js")

   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "mySearch", "mySearch('" & searchString & "')", True)
End Sub
```

/MyProject/script/functions/myFunc.js

```
function mySearch(searchString){
// ...
// logic for mySearch
// ...
}
```

I can't get the javascript function to be called and I need to reference the .js file at the end of my .apsx page. The error I get from the debugger is `Uncaught ReferenceError: mySearch is not defined`, please help.

Comment: If you want to call a javascript function, why are you making the call from the server side?

Comment: Within the btnSearch_ServerClick() function, I plan on adding a drop down to perform different behavior based on the selected item. One option would call the javascript, the other would make a non javascript call.

Comment: Ok, i'm still not sure I get the endgame here 100% but I only write MVC these days! :) I think your script needs wrapping in `<script language='javascript'></script>` for it to work client side though.

Comment: e.g. `"<script language='javascript'>mySearch('" & searchString & "')</script>"`

Comment: Based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20002287/1641172) question, it might be based on the name `mySearch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the criterion of choice is a dropdown, probably a better solution (I used jquery) is put the js file at the end of page, and check the dropdown value from javascrpit (here set as variable) and intercept the postback of .NET button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dropdown = 1;
        $('.midBtn').click(function () {
            if (dropdown == 1) {
                mySearch($('.midField').val());
                return false;
            } else {
                // ... postback
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

In this case you must be sure that the classes selector (midBtn and midField) are unique.